# Specific rows layout in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

is there a way to control the way the **flow of rows** in a **table** is managed ?

Instead of having a vertical flow, I'd like to group them by a given number and display the groups side-by-side.

This (non-standard) HTML code shows the expected result when the group size is 3, but uses more than one **table** :

```
<style type="text/css">
    table
    {
        float: left;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td, th
    {
        border: solid black 1px;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>John</td><td>Oregon</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>Joe</td><td>NY</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>Bobby</td><td>Texas</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>John</td><td>Oregon</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>Joe</td><td>NY</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td><td>Bobby</td><td>Texas</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>John</td><td>Oregon</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td><td>Joe</td><td>NY</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is the result obtained :

[image: Fake horizontal rows flow layout]

Comment: What's wrong with the way you've done it?

Comment: If I'm reading this right: stick with multiple tables. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091503/how-can-i-make-display-block-work-on-a-td-in-ie/5091822#5091822 - you (afaik) can't float table cells in IE7. Do you require IE7 support?

Comment: @JohnP : indeed, this way is not really problematic by itself, but a standard HTML/CSS option, if it exists, would be more flexible and would not clutter the resulting HTML code with tables so it will be simpler to parse for the browser and to manipulate with Javascript, eg with JQuery; moreover the server-side code necessary to generate this layout would be quite straight and then obvious.

Comment: @thirtydot : thanks for the info. I'd like it to work in Outlook, so in IE too. But, for my culture and future devs, if there is any standard way of doing it I'd like to know.

Comment: Nothing works in Outlook. You'll have to stick with HTML4 and basic layout, possibly even wrapping it in another table. Outlook is evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want `rowgroups` or `colgroups`. Rowgroups are created using `<tbody>`

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>John</td><td>Oregon</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>Joe</td><td>NY</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td><td>Bobby</td><td>Texas</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>John</td><td>Oregon</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td><td>Joe</td><td>NY</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

Then you might be able to place the groups side-by-side by changing the `tbody`s to `display:table` and floating them. This would give the appearance of side-by-side tables but still be semantically correct.

Comment: actually if Outlook is a target nothing this fancy will work. sorry.

Comment: thanks for this useful answer; it's not as straightforward as I'd expect, I'd particularly like to be able to declare the column headers only once, but is much cleaner than the multi-tables solution.