# Margin on tr's and border wont work out, css and html

Tags: html, css

Here's what I got:

http://jsfiddle.net/62hKs/2/

What I wish:

1. 1) Margin top 15px between the two red boxes you see
2. 2) In each 2 boxes it make it look like 4, I want to remove the
   middle red line, so there's only 2 and so it does not make the red
   line because the selectors are in a new td

What I did:

I did it my own way the red borders around the 4 tr's, because I couldnt find any smarter way after some research, then i tried #mytable tr{ margin: 15px } which does not work, also tried using margin within the css highlightedRowStart, highlightedRowMiddle, highlightedRowEnd but does not work either..

How can I apply the margin ?

Comment: try:  tr > td {margin-top:15px} instead. Or apply style='margin-top:15px' inside each td.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the display property to be block for margins to apply to table elements. By default the display property is set to table, which [does not respond to margin and padding rules](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/margin).

Try something like:

```
table {border: 1px solid #f00;}
tr {display:block}
tr:nth-child(5) {margin-top:15px;border-top:1px solid #f00;}
td:first-child {width:200px;}
```

Also, consider making the left cells labels on the select elements, or even better, abandoning the table for layout entirely. You might have more flexibility with `<section>` with two child `<ul>`'s where the `<li>` would contain the `<label>` and `<select>`:

```
<style>
  section { width:600px; }
  ul { border:1px solid #f00; margin:10px 0 0 0; padding:10px;}
  li { margin:8px 0; width:400px; clear:both; }
  select { float:right; }
</style>

<section>
  <ul>                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    <li>
      <label for='seats_timeclock[]'>Foo</label>
      <select name="seats_timeclock[]">
        <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
        <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
        <option value="09:00">09:00</option>         
      </select>          
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    <li>
      <label for='seats_timeclock[]'>Bar</label>
      <select name="seats_timeclock[]">
        <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
        <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
        <option value="09:00">09:00</option>         
      </select>          
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sSmCc/3/

Comment: You will have some weird behaviour from older versions of IE when applying `display: block` to `tr` and `td` as mentioned in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091503/how-can-i-make-display-block-work-on-a-td-in-ie.

Comment: All the more reason to avoid using the table for layout altogether :)

Comment: @Karem here's an example of the approach I was describing to the markup - http://jsfiddle.net/sSmCc/2/

Comment: @ckundo If i should use that ul method, how can i make the selector and the names nice formatted like when using tables? Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: Hey @Karem, I updated the answer to include more explicit detail on markup and styles. Good luck!

Comment: Also, come to think of it, you may want to consider fieldset instead of ul. It's a little less markup and probably more semantic.

Answer (score 0):

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/FypSu/

What you want is the old cellspacing html attribute. CSS equivalent is border-spacing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/62hKs/3/ I tried with your ex, and see the result. I dont want the spacing betwn the tr's INSIDE