# Display:table-cell not working in IE9?

Tags: css

I've got a table where I'm using the CSS display property to alter the layout. For full size browsers I use "block" and for smaller ones I use "table-cell".
It works great in Firefox, Safari and Chrome, but somehow IE9 seems to mess it up of course...
When I debug the page using Firebug and the likes, it's clear that all browsers except IE change the display:table-cell to display:block. But IE is stuck with display:block even though the CSS file clearly states it should be table-cell.

Is there any known issues with "table-cell" in IE9 or any known work arounds?

EDIT: 
The issue is not with table-cell, it's with Display:block on a table cell.

The problem I'm having can be found here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php
Open in Chrome/Firefox and resize browser window - the table is responsive and changes to a narrow design.
Open in IE9 and resize - the table is static and does not change.

EDIT2:
In the previous example the responsive part is commented out for IE, because the creator knew that it would be messy. Nevertheless, I want to be able to create this kind of design that works in IE as well, so I need to make some kind of workaround for it to make it work.

Here is a JSFiddle that shows how IE9 messes up the responsive table when reponsive part is included: http://jsfiddle.net/2Mt37/

Comment: I was considering to include some code but I figured since this is part of a huge project it wouldn't make much sense to include it anyway...

Comment: You're right. IE9 really screws this up. I fixed it with just a few changes so I hope that works for you.

Comment: The ones I made to your markup

Comment: I deleted my answer, since it didn't help you. That was the only obvious suggestion, so your question is now almost impossible to answer without a test case that reproduces the problem. Use http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://jsbin.com/ or just link directly to the afflicted site.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to post a real code example. But this site does the same thing as mine and has the same issues with IE9. Basically its a responsive table, try it in Firefox/Chrome and change browser size, its totally responsive: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php   But if you try it in IE9 it's stuck. Seems like there is an issue with Display:Block (not Table-cell as I first thought). Here's the original post to the example (which unfortunately doesnt seem to give any solution to the IE problem): http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: JSFiddle, try in Chrome and then IE and see the differences in responsive layout: http://jsfiddle.net/2Mt37/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer from an old thread, where @thirtydot wrote

> I applied **float: left** to stuff. It kinda works.

[How can I make "display: block" work on a <td> in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091503/how-can-i-make-display-block-work-on-a-td-in-ie)

As he said, it *kinda* works... IE9 stops rendering stuff all crazy, but there's still som aligning to do to make it look good.
But that answer is good enough, I can fix the rest myself...

Comment: This worked for me, thanks very much :) Could anyone please comment why float left works in this case?

Answer (score 6):

The X-UA-Compatible meta tag allows web page authors to select what version of Internet Explorer the page should be rendered as.

These are your options:

```
"IE=5"
"IE=EmulateIE7"
"IE=7"
"IE=EmulateIE8"
"IE=8"
"IE=EmulateIE9
"IE=9"
"IE=edge" which tells Internet Explorer to use the highest mode available to that version of IE.

But I recommend you to use this one:

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
```

chrome=1 is for Google's Chrome Frame which is an open source browser plug-in. Users who have the plug-in installed have access to Google Chrome's open web technologies and speedy JavaScript engine when they open pages in the browser. It enhances your browsing experience in Internet Explorer and give you access to the latest HTML5 features as well as Google Chrome’s performance and security features.

Comment: I don't think I can use the chrome-1 part since it's relying on the use to have a custom plug-in installed. I need the site to work with a clean installation of IE9, Chrome or Firefox..